# How do I change the copyright message and date on the splash screen on Xamarin IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, splash-screen

This is the default splash screen that first appears in my Xamarin IOS app before my own splash screen appears:

[image: my splash screen]

Where does the copyright message and date at the bottom come from?

How can I change it to at least display the correct year?

I've done a text search in the solution, but can't find any instances of 2017.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Got it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a blank iOS project in Visual Studio to check it. It's a label in LaunchScreen.xib, you can open it with xib editor or xml editor and just edit it:

```
<label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" 
                    contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" 
                    verticalHuggingPriority="251" 
                    text="  Copyright (c) 2018 " textAlignment="center" 
                    lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines"
                    minimumFontSize="9" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" 
                    id="8ie-xW-0ye">
                    (...)
</label>
```

Change following value: text="  **Copyright (c) 2018** "